# Is there a function that returns a date depending on the month assigned in Crystal Reports?

Tags: crystal-reports

Is there an existing function in Crystal Reports?

Something like function({myTable.myDateColumn, x) //Where x is the number of the month and the function will return a date

Not like Month({myTable.myDateColumn) = x //Which I believe will just return a number.

Reason being: I need to get that date and assign it to a variable.

Comment: If `myTable.myDateColumn` is already a date, what do you want the Crystal function to do?

Comment: If you want to get the Monthname (IE: get January instead of 1) use the aptly named MonthName() function.  If not: rephrase your question so we can understand what you require.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try the DateAdd() function.

```
//Add 2 months to the database value
DateAdd("m", 2, {myTable.DateColumn})

//Subtract 3 months from the database value
DateAdd("m", -3, {myTable.DateColumn})
```